# Code optimization for string comparisons

Tags: c, string, algorithm

I have a function code for string comparison as below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int max=0;

int calcMis(char *string,int i, int j,int len)
{
     int mis=0;
     int k=0;
     while(k<len)
     {
             if(string[i+k]!=string[j+k])
                mis+=1;
             if((mis+len-k-1)<=max)
                 return 1;
             else if(mis>max)
                 return 0;
             k=k+1;
     }
}

int main()
{
    char *input=malloc(2000*sizeof(char));
    scanf("%d",&max);
    scanf("%s",input);
    int c=0,i,j,k,x,mis=0;
    int len=strlen(input);
    i=0;
    while(i<len-1)
    {
        j=i;
        while(j<len-1)
         {
             k=i+1;
             x=j-i+1;
             if(x<=max)
                 c=c+len-k-x+1;
             else
                while(k+x<=len)
                {
                  if(strncmp(input+i,input+k,x+1)==0)
                   {
                      if(max>=0)
                          c=c+x;
                   }
                  else
                   c+=calcMis(input,i,k,x);
                  k=k+1;
                }       
            j=j+1;
         }
        i=i+1;
    }   
    printf("%d",c);
    return 0;   
}
```

This codes is the solution for the question :

> Given a string S and and integer K, find the integer C which equals
>   the number of pairs of substrings(S1,S2) such that S1 and S2 have
>   equal length and Mismatch(S1, S2) <= K where the mismatch function is
>   defined below.

eg : abc then the substrings are {a,ab,abc,b,bc,c}

Is there any better method than this. Is there any optimizations possible in this code?

Comment: Well I see no reason to make the interface depend on both substrings being in the same superstring. Why not just take two pointer arguments and pass `string+i` and `string+j` from the caller? That's more general and reduces the working data set by 1.

Comment: Why not use `strncmp` with the first and second arguments being: `str+i` and `str+j`?

Comment: @Tuntuni: I need to count the mismatches not just whether a string come before or after in alphabetical order

Comment: @ranger What is `max`?

Comment: This is one of those interfaces that makes me puke because it takes `char *` and doesn't modify it at all. If this was C++, it would use `std::string` as well, and could make use of `std::mismatch`.

Comment: Why have you tagged this question C++ if you're using C-style strings? And if you're using C++, why aren't you using `std::string`?

Comment: @Tuntuni: max denotes the upper bound for number of mismatches

Comment: @chris: if it were using C++, it would be a waste to use `std::string`; C++14 will bring std::string_ref, but until then nothing prevents you from defining it yourself.

Comment: @R..: Question edited with much more details and code...

Comment: @Tuntuni:Question edited with much more details and code...

Comment: @CodyGray much better: ***Why have you tagged the question as C++ and you are using `malloc`?***

Comment: I'm reviewing the code and I don't find anything about C++. **Its everything C code** (C io, C includes, `malloc`, raw-pointers/dynamic arrays instead of `std::string`, etc). So I'm going to modify the tags

Comment: @Manu Not really. If he used `std::string`, there would be no reason to use `malloc`. Got to fix the problem at its source.

Comment: @CodyGray What i'm trying to point out is if he was using C++, he would use `operator new`, not `malloc`. And this is only one of the things. Check my last comment.

Comment: @ranger Could you add the problem description definition of `Mismatch(S1, S2)`?

Comment: Different (better) solutions for a problem - okay for [so]. Optimize code - should be on [codereview.se]. You seem to be asking for both, which you shouldn't be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea that might help. First of all, compare all pairs of characters in the string:

```
void compare_all(char* string, int length, int* comp)
{
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < length; ++i1)
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < length; ++i2)
            result[i1 * length + i2] = (string[i1] != string[i2]);
}
```

Here `comp` represents a square matrix containing values 0 and 1. Each pair of substrings corresponds to a diagonal section in this matrix. For example, for the string "testing", the following section of the matrix represents substrings "tes" and "tin".

```
. . . O . . .
. . . . O . .
. . . . . O .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
```

You have to count how many sections have sum of elements no more than `k`. To do that, examine all the diagonals that are parallel to the main diagonal, one by one. In order not to count things twice, look only at those that are below (or above) the main diagonal (let's include the main diagonal for simplicity).

```
int count_stuff(int* comp, int n, int k)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (diag = 0; diag < n; ++diag)
    {
        int* first_element_in_diagonal = comp + diag;
        int jump_to_next_element = n + 1;
        int length_of_diagonal = n - diag;
        result += count_stuff_on_diagonal(
            first_element_in_diagonal,
            jump_to_next_element,
            length_of_diagonal,
            k);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now, the problem is a much simpler one: find the number of sections along a sequence of integers, for which the sum is not greater than `k`. The most straightforward method is by enumerating all such sections.

```
int count_stuff_on_diagonal(int* comp, int jump, int n, int k)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < n; ++i1)
        for (int i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < n; ++i2)
        {
            int* first_element_in_section = comp + i1 * jump;
            int mismatches = count_sum_of_section(
                first_element_in_section,
                jump,
                i2 - i1);
            if (mismatches <= k)
                ++result;
        }
    return result;
}
```

To improve the speed of calculating a sum across a section of consecutive integers, build a table of [cumulative sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum); use it instead on the matrix of 0s and 1s.

(Please excuse me for not using `const` and VLA, and occasional syntax errors).

Comment: Main question is - what is a complexity of your algo?

Comment: Good, did you think about O(n^2*k) solution? I believe it should exist using DP.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** This analysis was made *before* he/she edited the post and included the rest of his/her code. He/she made no mention to the `main` function in the original post (in which I supplied my answer to).

---

Looking at your code for `calcMis`, here are some of the readability and style improvements I would make:

- Remove all of the return statements from within the loop. Not a big deal for small loops but a much bigger deal in larger loops as it's harder to debug when it has 3 or 4 extra cases to leave the loop.
- Redefine your parameters with respect to what the function does.

Your algorithm runs in  order `n` but we can reduce some of the operations it performs. My analysis of your algorithm is as follows:

```
assignment operator            (=)  x4: O(1)
while loop                          x1: O(n), where n is len.
  dereference operator           (*)  x2: O(1)
  less than operator             (<)  x1: O(1)
  does not equal operator        (!=) x1: O(1)
  addition operator              (+)  x4: O(1)
  subtraction operator           (-)  X2: O(1)
  less than or equal to operator (<=) x1: O(1)
  Order: O(n) + 2 * O(1) + O(1) + O(1) + 4 * O(1) + 2 * O(1) + 1 * O(1) = O(n)
Order: 4 * O(1) + O(n) = O(n)
```

Here is the improved algorithm (micro efficiency and readability improvements) -- still of a linear order but less instructions and takes advantage of `const` optimizations by the compiler:

```
bool calcMis( char const * const str, int const i, int const j, int const len ) {
  // Checks pre conditions.
  assert( str != NULL );

  // Determines if the length is 0, if so return 0 mismatches.
  if ( len == 0 ) return true;

  // Determines if we are comparing at the same index, if so return 0 mismatches.
  if ( i == j ) return true;

  // Defines an integer mis, holds the number of mismatches.
  int mis = 0;

  // Iterates over the entire string of length len.
  for ( int k = 0; ( k < len ) && ( mis < max ); k++ ) {
    // Determines whether there was a mismatch at positions i and j.
    if ( str[ i + k ] != str[ j + k ] ) mis += 1;
  }

  // Defines a bool result, determines whether we have had too many mismatches.
  bool const result = !( mis > max );

  return result;
}
```

Comment: `mis += 1` -> `mis++`

Comment: @H2CO3, with the significance of that being? (and I am well aware of that)

Comment: `calcMis` has complexity O(n) but it is called from nested loops (3 levels deep), so the algorithm runs in O(n^4) (not sure about the last part, but definitely not O(n)). It needs total redesign, not readability improvements.

Comment: @anatolyg, my response was made before he edited his original post and included the rest of his code. He made no mention of this prior to my analysis.

Comment: shame on the compiler which cannot figure out those values are constants.. :/